# Reducing Spacing in Python Output in VS Code

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

The output of a pandas dataframe of 20 lines takes a full page because of very high spacing as depicted below:
[image]

Can this be changed in VS code settings or in some python settings?

Comment: What does this show?

`display(df.head(20))`

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting in VScode: in terminal, integrated, letter spacing.